WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies when deploying on jboss
I'm trying to configure a datasource in my application, I'm using jboss abd ojdbc7, and this is the current relevant configuration:
jboss-web.xml
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db_risk</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <jndi-name>java:jboss/jdbc/db_risk</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>

web.xml
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/db_risk</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>

standalone.xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/db_risk" pool-name="DB_RISK" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@111.11.1.11:1111:oraRsk</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>
                    <password>PASSWORD</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
<drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc7">
                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>

When the application is deployed I get the following error:
17:26:49,267 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "kyc.war")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [    
    "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.db_risk"
],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [       
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.app.app.env.jdbc.db_risk is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.db_risk]"]"
]

The oracle driver is correctly configured and loaded, what am I missing?
Thanks in advance
